# How to add Creation time and last update of a record in a snowflake table

Tags: sql, datatables, sql-update, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, creation

I am kinda new to snowflake and trying to add two columns to an existing table

Below are the two columns

1. Creation Time
2. Last update Time

Could someone please help me in achieving this to an existing SNOWFLAKE table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi , you need to use the ALTER table script as  "ALTER  table table_name add column_name  datatype";. If you want to capture the insert/update then you can make them as default current_timestamp().

Answer (score 2):

You can create these two columns but Snowflake will not be able to update data into them by himself.

You will have to update these technical fields while inserting / updating data into the given table.

You should have a look on the [MERGE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html) feature.
You can for exemple :

- **WHEN NOT MATCHED** : insert new row with **creation_time** and **last_update_time** at current timestamp.
- **WHEN MATCHED** : update **last_update_time** with current timestamp.

Here is a nice exemple of what could be achieved usiong MERGE + STREAM + TASKS to build ome scd type 2 tables :
[Building a Type 2 Slowly Changing Dimension in Snowflake Using Streams and Tasks](https://www.snowflake.com/blog/building-a-type-2-slowly-changing-dimension-in-snowflake-using-streams-and-tasks-part-1/?lang=fr)